# Is this yeast classed as instant yeast?

Tags: baking, bread, yeast

I want to do [this recipe](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/pauls_mincemeat_and_33176) which contains these ingredients for the bread part..

```
250g/9oz strong white bread flour, plus extra for dusting
5g salt
8g instant yeast
50g/1¾oz unsalted butter, softened, plus extra for greasing
135ml/4½fl oz whole milk
1 free-range egg, lightly beaten
```

and the method...

1. Tip the flour into a large mixing bowl, then add the salt to one side of the bowl and the yeast to the other. Add the butter, milk and egg and stir the mixture with your fingers until it comes together as a dough. Continue mixing until the sides of the bowl are clean and the dough is soft.
2. Turn out the dough onto a lightly floured surface and knead for 5-6 minutes, or until the dough has stopped feeling sticky and has a smooth, silky exterior. Return the dough to the bowl, cover with cling film and set aside to prove in a warm room for at least 30 minutes and up to one hour.

Its asks for `instant yeast` - I have [this yeast](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/flour/allinson-dried-active-baking-yeast-125g) described as Dried active baking yeast, suitable for hand-baking only.

Is this the same thing? I couldn't find 'instant yeast'. Can I use this yeast in this recipe and can I use it exactly as described in the method?

Comment: The phrase "Suitable for hand baking only" is your clue here: instant yeast is popular for many reasons, but the first is probably because it works far better in bread machines (since you can't really mix yeast with water in those).  "Bread Machine Yeast" is often instant yeast.  You can tell by looking at it; it's more crystalline in appearance than regular dried yeast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is just normal dried yeast. Allinson do an [instant yeast](http://www.allinsonflour.co.uk/products/easy-bake-yeast.html) (they call it Easy Bake yeast) that comes in a green container.

You can still use your dried yeast though. Use double the amount, and instead of adding it to the flour, add it to the milk (which should be warmed very gently first - not hot, just 'finger warm'). Let it sit for 5 minutes and get bubbly, then proceed as normal.

Comment: Oh so I've made my life more difficult! Typical :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instant yeast and bread machine yeast are the same. They need no proofing or activation. Active dry yeast needs to be activated by proofing it in warm water for a few minutes, til it gets frothy. Often a bit of sugar is added as well to give the yeast a boost.